# Prog can't run on page 113 of <<Lisp in small pieces>>

Tags: scheme, lisp

The code from page 113 of `Lisp in small pieces` seems can't run on r5rs environment of racket:

```
(let ((name "Hemo"))
 (set! winner (lambda () name))
 (set! set-winner! (lambda (new-name) (set! name new-name) name ))
 (set-winner! "Me")
 (winner) )
```

and:

```
(let ((name "Nemo"))
 (set! winner (lambda () name))
 (winner) )
```

both got error:

```
cannot set variable before its definition
variable: winner
```

is the code of this book wrong?or I should not use scheme?I have to use the lisp this book defined to run this code?Thanks!

Comment: The Scheme dialect you're using doesn't allow to `set!` a variable before _defining_ it. Either define it first or switch to a dialect that allows it, like the book's Lisp.

Comment: I tried running it in r6rs under Dr Racket - same problem.

Comment: The book is several years older than R5RS...  I'm not certain that it would work in R4RS either, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the variable using `define` or `lambda`. For example:

```
(let ((name "Hemo"))
    (define winner #t)
    (define set-winner! #t)
 (set! winner (lambda () name))
 (set! set-winner! (lambda (new-name) (set! name new-name) name ))
 (set-winner! "Me")
 (winner) )
```

`set!` is converted into an scode whose semantics is to mutate a location of memory, not to bind new locations.  Forms like `let` are syntactic sugar for the combination of both operations (bind+mutation) and, because they are so common, Queinnec inserted an scode, fixlet, for this combination.

All these things are explained in the book of Queinnec.  Go on reading!